# How to check if all values in a 2D list are 0?

Tags: python

I want my program to check if my two-dimensional list is full of 0

```
usedGameboardPosition = [[0 for x in range(16)] for x in range(16)]
```

This is declaration that I later on in program fill with 1.

I tried to check it with this:

```
if all(v == 0 for v in usedGameboardPosition):
  start = 0
```

But it seems to not work. Although list is full of 0 it doesn't go into the condition.

Answer (score 5):

Each element `v` in the list in `usedGameboardPosition` is a list of `0`s. For this to work you want to iterate those inner lists and check that the elements contained in them (`x` in the example here) is equal to 0.

```
if all(x == 0 for v in usedGameboardPosition for x in v):
    start = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not check if v == 0 since v is a list of 0. Try this instead:

```
x = [[0 for x in range(16)] for x in range(16)]

print all(all(y == 0 for y in z) for z in x)
```

Answer (score 1):

If your game board contains only positive (or only negative) numeric values in addition to zero, you can use `sum()`.

```
if not sum(sum(row) for row in usedGameboardPosition):
    # it added up to zero, so it was all zeroes
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through the inner lists as well:

```
usedGameboardPosition = [[0 for x in range(16)] for x in range(16)]

if all(all(x == 0 for x in v)  for v in usedGameboardPosition):
    print "All zeroes!"
```

You can [test the above with different values on ideone](https://ideone.com/3HbkVp).

Answer (score 0):

Inverted logic sometimes wins the day:

```
if all(not any(row) for row in usedGameboardPosition):
    start = 0
```

Answer (score -1):

I didn't find a solution here, but I found this worked for me

```
all(x == 0 for x in list(usedGameboardPosition))
```

Comment: What was `usedGameboardPosition` in your case? I don't see how that answers ***this*** question...